# Is it possible to create a client-side workspace-based app in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I wish to create a client-side only app in Angular2 where the user is prompted to select a folder on his hard-disk as a workspace, meaning that files will be written by the app inside that folder. I want to know how that can be achieved or if it is even possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it works with Angular or not, but you could check out https://electron.atom.io/

Comment: I was just taking a look at that and apparently it does work with Angular. Check https://auth0.com/blog/create-a-desktop-app-with-angular-2-and-electron/ for more info.

Comment: That's pretty cool. But you might also want to ensure that the features you intend to use are available to electron.

Comment: I suppose you could use AJAX and PHP to access the system's files if you really need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

JavaScript, running in a web browser, outside of a browser extension, cannot write to the user's file system.

It can only read from files explicitly selected using a file input.

The closest you'll come to an exception is for internal browser storage areas such as localStorage.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR no.

But you can use [File and Directory Entries API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API) which works [only in Chrome and Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem) and is non standard.

And I do not recomend it to use this, same as the documentation says:

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: Indeed, the task I've been given requires the app to work on all platforms. I wanted to know if I could avoid server-side programming completely, but it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Unfortunately Javascript on web is not capable of doing that at the moment.

Comment: The [File and Directory Entries API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API) *aka* just “Entries API” https://wicg.github.io/entries-api is now supported in some version of all major browser engines — it just shipped today in Safari Technology Preview Release https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/ and it has been supported already in Edge for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It's possible if you use a framework such as [Electron](https://electron.atom.io), in which you can use Angular2. 
This approach does not utilize a browser,  it appears as a "normal" application on the computer.